# Laravel 5.5 - Merge 2 collections into one based on id?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

So I have 2 models `Books` and `Classes`:

```
$books = Books::limit(3)->get(['id','classable_id','easy_book']);
// Books returned:
{ id: 200,
  classable_id: 2,
  easy_book: false
},
{ id: 201,
  classable_id: 3,
  easy_book: true
},
{ id: 202,
  classable_id: 4,
  easy_book: false
}

$classIds = $books->pluck('classable_id');

$classes = Classes::whereIn('id', $classIds);
// Classes returned:
{ id: 2, 
  subject: Math, 
  students: 30
},
{ id: 3, 
  subject: History, 
  students: 30
},
{ id: 4,
  subject: Physics,
  students: 30
}
```

Then trying to get the following output (without combining the queries, but keeping them separate like above, and just using php logic to output):

```
Classes returned:
{ id: 2,
  subject: Math,
  students: 30.
  easy_book: false }, // trying to merge this!
{ id: 3,
  subject: History,
  students: 30.
  easy_book: true}, // trying to merge this!
{ id: 4,
  subject: Physics,
  students: 30.
  easy_book: false } // trying to merge this!
```

Basically, I am trying to merge the `easy_book` field from `books` returned to the respective `class` returned based on `class.id == books.classable_id`. Any idea how to merge it?

Comment: It would make more sense, be be easier to just do this at the database level instead. Can you post the code for your models and the relationship definitions between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a relationship to your Books model like so:

```
public function class() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Classes::class, 'id', 'classable_id);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Book::with('class')->select('id', 'classable_id', 'easy_book')->limit(3)->get();
```

Each collection item will then have a collection of classes where applicable.

If after that you want to manipulate them, you can use the map function as documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map

Comment: You're missing the `->get()` from the end of your query builder chain.

Comment: Also, if `classable_id` is on the `Book` model, I'm wondering if a `Book` belongs to a `Class`, not the other way around. But I am guessing without seeing the code.

Comment: I agree. I'm used to the likes of a Book having multiple genres, forgot about the relevance of the `classible_id` in this scenario.